# MySQL Query - IF or CASE with AND & Exceptions (for calculations)

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, phpmyadmin, case-when

SQL Query - extract cell value for calculations as below

**Info:**  Server version: 5.1.39
**Php:**  5.4
MySQL / phpMyAdmin
**Server:**  Apache
**Code is run via:** Server SQL Query (copy & paste in the phpMyAdmin) or in MySQL Workbench or using a custom shopping cart manager.
**Exports to:** Excel (.csv then to .xlsx for sales reports)
**Other:** I do use a number of tables for referencing

I am trying to write a string (so far WHEN & IF) to do the following:

```
T5.coupon_code = XYZABC
AND T3.products_id=14  then the value is $5.00
as Ded_Promo

T5.coupon_code = XYZABC
AND (T3.products_id=Anything else)  then the value is $0.00
as Ded_Promo
```

(see table lines 1 & 2 for example).

**code tried:**

```
(IF(T5.coupon_code=XYZABC And T3.products_id=14,'5.00','0.00')) As Ded_promo2,
```

Result:  Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'XYZABC' in 'field list'

The coupon_code value is legit, when I run a query on the coupon_code the code that I am wanting to query shows as being used. (XYZABC is substituted for my real code).

**Also tried:**

```
CASE When (T5.coupon_code = XYZABC) then '5.00'
end As Ded_Promo,
```

Same error as above.

I then need to have the code further expanded to show:

```
If code & product match = $5.00 As Ded_Promo (as above)
```

But if code is present (say ID: ABC123DEF), then 'value' (as listed) As `Disc_CoupVal`

Ideally I need to make sure that the Promo discount doesn't get attributed to other products in the order, whilst the front end calculates it as 1 sale. My reports require that I keep discount coupons and special promotions connected to ONLY the product they are discounting. Commissions rely on this.

However I still need to see all other coupons listed and attribute them across an entire order of 1 or more products.

There will never be more than 1 `coupon_code` on any given order, the store doesn't allow it.

From above:

```
orderid | couponcode  | ProdID | Discount
21      | XYZABC      | 14     | 5.00
21      | XYZABC      | 12     | 0.00
36      | ABC123DEF   | 3      | 2.50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(IF(T5.coupon_code=XYZABC And T3.products_id=14,'5.00','0.00')) As Ded_promo2
```

This is causing an error because you are using XYZABC as a column name. Use it as a string:

```
(IF(T5.coupon_code='XYZABC' And T3.products_id=14,'5.00','0.00')) As Ded_promo2
```

Edit:

In response to your comments, you can include these in the same column but it's a bit messier:

```
(IF(
     T5.coupon_code='XYZABC' And T3.products_id=14,
     '5.00',
      (IF(
           T5.coupon_code='AnyotherCoupon' And T3.products_id='AnyotherID',
      'CouponValue',
       '0.00'))
 )) As Ded_promo2,
```

So the above will show `5` if the code is `XYZABC` and product id is `14`.

Otherwise if code is `AnyotherCoupon` and id is `AnyotherID` it will show `CouponValue`.

If neither of these are the case then it will show `0.00`.

One thing to note that if there is a lot of these it would be better to store the promotion amount in the database (perhaps as a coupon table?). This keeps the SQL neater and allows you to more easily add and change coupons.

Comment: Thank you Jim.
How do I then go about part 2, if the coupon is another code? I need them to work together, so exclude one from the other complete. :)  
Or will this not affect the regular coupon_code results?

Comment: @MrsAdmin Can you provide an example of the output you need?

Comment: Sorry, my lack of knowhow on here made my table wonky.  
I don't know the code to add an exception, but the example would be in the little table as above.

So when I call the SELECT query I now use the corrected code you supplied then I need it to not exclude other coupon_code data in the system.

Comment: Looking at my query as a whole - in a basic way:
(IF(T5.coupon_code='XYZABC' And T3.products_id=14,'5.00','0.00')) As Ded_promo2,    |  
(IF(T5.coupon_code='AnyotherCoupon' And T3.products_id='AnyotherID','CouponValue','0.00')) As Ded_promo2,    |  
Can I get all results in the one column?  Or do I need to have 2?  (1 for regular coupons & 1 for the promo). If I can put them in the 1 column that would be superb.

Comment: @MrsAdmin I've updated my answer and added some more details.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.  I do have a coupon table. It stores all the coupon_code & coupon_amount, however it doesn't stipulate if it is % or $ discount.  We have some of both. Signup code=15% off.  Promo for a product=$5 off.    It is only the 'promo' codes that are needing to be treated carefully as they are related to a specific product and can not affect another products sales value in the EoM accounts.   NewSignup=%15, orderID=12 = $6.00 discount  or orderID=30 = $15 discount, depending on the complete order total.

Comment: It's nearly 3:30am, I should have done this earlier.  
'(IF(T5.coupon_code='XYZABC' And T3.products_id=14,'5.00','0.00')) As ot_coupon2,'
'(select value from /*PREFIX*/orders_total T5 where orders_id = T2.orders_id and class = 'ot_coupon') As ot_coupon2,'
Both do as they should reporting the $$value of the total discount, however they resolve to separate columns so I now have 2x ot_coupon2 rather than 1.

Answer (score 0):

(IF(T5.coupon_code='XYZABC' And T3.products_id=14,'5.00','0.00')) As Ded_promo2,

Try putting single quotes around the XYZABC.  This makes the term a literal character string, instead of a named data item in SQL.